# I got " TypeError: Storage location can only .."

Tags: solidity, storage, memory

Here is my sample contract code, but I got an error,

```
TypeError: Storage location can only be given for array or struct types.
```

I just wannted to define some element of a structure in a function,

```
contract MyContract {
   PC[] public pcs;
   structure PC {
      string name,
      uint time
   }

   function checkTime(uint _pcid) public {
      uint memory a = pcs[_pcid];
      string memory b = pcs[_pcid];
      //do something with a and b...
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? do I have to define storage instead of memory??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is not correct. The base type doesn't have the storage location. Its reserved for array or struct.

So you either do

```
PC memory structure = pcs[_pcid];
```

or

```
uint a = pcs[_pcid].time;
string memory b = pcs[_pcid].name;
```

Comment: Thanks, But when I try to compile (0.4.21), I've got,  " Warning: Variable is declared as a storage pointer. Use an explicit "storage" keyword to silence this warning." for a string variable. why there is no warning message for uint type?

Comment: oh, sorry yes. memory has to be used for string type since its dynamically resolved. For other base type is not necessary